# Component (tooltip) priority over other component(s)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tooltip

Please note that I am using React.

I am trying to add a tooltip to the ".preview" component which is basically a little box with a letter in it (the little boxes represents the days of the week, although this is not important).

The tooltip shows as expected but it gets shown behind the footer text.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKmKm.png)

ClassCard.jsx

```
<div className={`card ${isCardOpen ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={toggleCard}>
    <header className="card-header">
        <div className="image-container">
            <img src={card_image} alt="image" />
            <a className="card-number">{number}</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    { name ? <p className="card-name">{name}</p> : <p className="placeholder card-name">Undefined</p> }
    <div className="card-body">
        { teacher && (<p className="card-teacher">{teacher} { teacherOffice && `- (${teacherOffice})`}</p>)}
        { schedule && (<div className="schedule-container">
            <p className="card-schedule-title">Horaire:</p>
            <div className="card-schedule-preview">
                { Object.keys(schedule).map(day => (
                <div className={`preview ${isNull ? 'empty' : ''}`}>
                    <a>{button_text}</a>
                    {!isNull && <div className="tooltip preview-tooltip">
                        <span>Heure : {hover_text.time}</span>
                        <span>Local : {hover_text.local}</span>
                    </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>) }
    </div>
    <div className="card-footer">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClock}></FontAwesomeIcon>
        <span className="card-footer-text">Prochain travail dû dans {workTime}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

ClassCard.css

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 167px;
    margin: 10px 10px 90px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: height 0.6s, width 0.6s, margin 0.6s;
}

.card-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;

    & img {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        transition: transform 0.4s ease;
    }
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.card-number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 0 -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.card-name {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin: 7px 7px 18px;
}

.card-body {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-10px);
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
}

.card-teacher {
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
}

.card-schedule-title {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
}

.schedule-container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 10px 22px;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-schedule-preview {
    display: flex;
}

.card-footer {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.card-footer-text {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.card:hover {
    height: 249px;
    width: 310px;
    margin: 5px 5px 10px;

    .card-number {
        font-size: 55px;
        text-shadow: 2px 7px 5px rgba(100,100,100,0.3), 0 -4px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }

    .card-header img {
        transform: scale(1.15);
    }

    .card-body {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
        transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 1s;
    }

}

.preview {
    position: relative;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.preview-tooltip span {
    display: block;
}

.preview.empty {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.preview:hover > .preview-tooltip {
    display: block;
}

.preview:not(.empty):hover {
    background-color: #08a45c;
    color: white;
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% + 10px);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #5a616e;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: 'Museo', sans-serif;
}
```

This is due to the fact that the `.cardfooter` has it's position set to "absolute". Setting it's position to "static" fixes my issue. However, now the component (the footer) cannot move when the card expends when I hover over it. I need it to be absolute so that I can "transform" it.

I will gladly take any idea! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set card-body z-index must be over than card-footer z-index value

```
.card-body {
    z-index: 2;
}
.card-footer {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This might be works...

Result:
[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I did not put the index on the card-body (I put it on the tooltip instead) which was why it was not working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

add z-index in .tooltip css

```
.tooltip{
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I tried that with z-index at 1 on .card but it does not fix it...

Comment: 1 is default , so setting it to 1 wont make any change , make it 999

Answer (score 0):

Give tooltip a higher z-index; value more than 1

```
.tooltip{
   z-index: 2 or smth;
}
```

since the tooltip has position: absolute, the z-index property should work as expected.